# Display specific output based on order MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a following table.

```
ID Name State Date
1   A1   First 1/10/2013
2   A1   Second 1/11/2013
3   A1   Last   1/12/2013
4   A2   First  1/10/2013
5   A2   Closed 1/11/2013
6   A3   First  1/10/2012
7   A3   Second 1/10/2012
```

The order of preference of state is as follows

```
 1 First
 2 Second
 3 Last
 4 Closed
```

Which means that I have to display only the latest state of the Name (provided the state is not closed. In case the state is closed, I do not have to display that ID).

So the output of the above table should be

```
ID Name State Date
3  A1    Last  1/12/2013
7  A3    Second 1/10/2012
```

I'm not sure how to proceed? I would have tried something had I'd known but for now I'm struggling with it. I can do this in `php` and store the output in another `table/view` and display it but it has to be done in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `ID` is auto_incremented.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  name, MAX(ID) max_ID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY Name
        ) b ON  a.ID = b.max_ID AND
                a.Name = b.Name
WHERE   a.State <> 'Closed'
```

or if the datatype of column date is `DATE`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  name, MAX(date) max_date
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY Name
        ) b ON  a.ID = b.max_date AND
                a.Name = b.Name
WHERE   a.State <> 'Closed'
```

Comment: OMG Yes my column ID is auto incremented.. DUH !! I could have used that.. Thanks a lot ..but two states can be on the same date..

Comment: so which query do you prefer? the first one or the second one?

Comment: The first one.. but you can keep the second one too.. (might be useful for someone in future)

Comment: @Ankur does it solve the problem or do i need another modification?

Answer (score 0):

I also came with such a solution but I'm not sure if mine is faster or not.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT id, name, state, date FROM myTable ORDER BY state DESC, id DESC) AS subQuery
WHERE state <> 'Closed' GROUP BY name
```

**EDIT:** I tried it this way because GROUP BY will only return you the first item, not the last one, so by first ordering it to put first the one you look for then grouping them, you get it!